# Refinement of a B specification

Tags: formal-verification, formal-methods, refinement-type, b-method

Consider I have the following in B specification :-

```
flower <: FLOWER
age <: AGE
owner <: OWNER
Type <: flower * age
Buyer : owner <-> flower
```

Is it possible for me to create a refinement as followed :-

```
flower <: FLOWER
age <: AGE
owner <: OWNER
Type : Owner <-> flower * age
Buyer : owner <-> flower
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: both unclear what you're asking and seemingly off-topic (https://math.stackexchange.com/ perhaps)

Comment: @RachelGallen: I think the question is on-topic because the B-Method is a software development method and here even concrete code is shown.

Comment: @danielp depends what you call "concrete".. consider editing the wiki on b-method for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible because in a refinement a variable's type must have the same type as in the specification (if there is a variable with the same name in the specification like here).